# array of lists in php

Tags: php, arrays, list

I would like to read all files from a directory, and store them in an array of lists. The keys in the array is the starting letter of the filename, and the list contains all names starting with that letter.

Example:
key 'a' may contain a1, a2, a3, a4
key 'b' may contain boat.txt, boast.txt, beast.txt

I have the file scan code in place, but am confused about how to use lists in an array in PHP. Can you help with that?

Thanks!

Comment: What does the scan code output? The file names? Also, is the scan code recursive through all directories located within a directory?

Comment: PHP does not have "lists". I presume you are talking about nested arrays.

Answer (score 3):

You will want to iterate through the list returned by your read function. If it's an array you can iterate like this (otherwise, explode your string results into an array and iterate through). You can use array sorts to alphabetize your arrays.

```
<?php

$somelist = array("awesomeness", "stupidness", "funniness", "alotness", "lolz0rz", "sorryness");
$newlist = array();

foreach($somelist as $val)
{
    $newlist[substr($val,0,1)][] = $val;
}

print "<pre>";
print_r($newlist);
print "</pre>";

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $first_char = substr($filename, 0, 1); // 'hello.doc' -> 'h'
 $files[$first_char][] = $filename; // add $filename to the $files array under the 'h' key.
```

Comment: Or use the array access operator on the string: `$string[0]`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for helping a php newbie :-)

Here's what I ended up with:

```
$dirname = "./filesdir/";
$dh = opendir( $dirname ) or die("Couldn't open directory [".$dirname."]");
$arr = array();
while ( ! ( ( $file = readdir( $dh ) ) === false) ) 
{
    if( $file != "." && $file != ".." )
    {
        if ( !is_dir("$dirname/$file" ) && substr_count($file, '.') == 1 )
        {
            $ext = strstr($file, '.', true);
            $key = substr($ext,0,1);

            if( $key < 'a' || $key > 'z' )
            {
                $key="other";
            }
            $arr[$key][] = $ext;
        }
    }
}
closedir( $dh );
print_r($arr);
```